# SSH "reverse" ProxyCommand

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, tunnel

Normally you have a setup like:

```
Workstation -> Firewall -> Server
```

Were your *Workstation* cannot contact *Server* directly, but has to use log in into *Firewall* first in order to contact *Server*.
In this "easy" setup you can use this setting on your workstation:

```
Host server
    ProxyCommand ssh firewall nc %h %p
```

**Now my question:**

The setup that was forced upon me is more difficult:

```
Workstation -> Intermediate <- Server
```

- I.e. my *Workstation* can log in into *Intermediate* and *Server* can log in into *Intermediate*.
- *Intermediate* cannot open a TCP connection to *Server*, but the other direction is possible.
- I cannot open a TCP connection in either direction between my *Workstation* and the *Server*. The packets simply won't be routed in the VLAN.
- I can "physically" access the *Server*, but I'd like to sit at my *Workstation*.

Now, how can I SSH from my machine to the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using ssh tunneling it is fairly easy; first go to your Server machine and run:

```
ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 intermediateuser@Intermediate
```

this opens port 2222 on intermediate machine, reverse forwarding connections to port 22 on the server.

Then you can

```
ssh user@Intermediate
```

and from there

```
ssh serveruser@localhost -p 2222
```

Or alternatively, you might bring port 2222 on Intermediate to your workstation with:

```
ssh -L 2222:localhost:2222 intermediateuser@Intermediate
```

then:

```
ssh serveruser@localhost -p 2222
```

Comment: Can you still do this without having an SSH server in `Server`? 
If so, would you proceed exactly the same?